# Why is my while loop not breaking when it should

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

I am currently trying to make a program that runs a simulation where a baseball player has an 81% chance of hitting the ball, and the goal is for the baseball player to get 56 hits in a row. I have it set up so that it will run a million repetitions of this, but it should stop if the player gets 56 or more hits in a row, and will print the attempt number that the player hit 56 hits in a row. However, for some reason, my for loop does not stop when the number of total hits is at least 56 (The predicted probability is much lower than 1/1000000). Why is my loop not breaking correctly?

```
import random
attempts = 0
totalhits = 0
def baseball():
    totalhits = 0
    hit = 1
    while hit == 1:
        odds = random.randint(1,100)
        if odds <= 81:
            hit = 1
            totalhits = totalhits + 1
        else:
            hit = 0
    return totalhits

for i in range(1,1000000):
    baseball()
    if totalhits >= 56:
        break
    attempts = attempts + 1

print("Attempt " + str(attempts) + " succeeded.")
```

The result is consistently 
`Attempt 999999 succeeded`

Comment: `if totalhits >= 56: break` needs to be inside your while loop. At the moment it's not only outside your while loop, but in a totally different function.

Comment: ``totalhits`` within ``baseball()`` is a **different variable** from ``totalhits`` in the global scope. It's all about **scope**. You either have to work with the return value of ``baseball()`` or use the ``global`` keyword.

Comment: @TomDalton Thats totally wrong.

Comment: you also say you need to "get 56 or more hits in a row". But both the variable name "total hits" and the way you're counting it, means that you're counting the toital hits the player got, not the maximum "hits in a row"

Comment: @Poojan can you explain what is wrong with what I've said?

Comment: I added a ```print(totalhits)``` right after the baseball() function is called in the for loop, and it is printing a string of 0s. Why is totalhits staying equal to 0 even though baseball() should be returning the actual number of hits?

Comment: As the answer below says, you effectively have 2 separate totalhits variables - the global one in the outer scope, and the function-local variable in the baseball function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need to capture the value your are returning from baseball.Or use `global`.
- The variable `totalhits` you used inside `baseball` function is not same as you declared in global level.
- Read more about variable scope in python to understand better.

```py
import random
attempts = 0
totalhits = 0
def baseball():
    totalhits = 0
    hit = 1
    while hit == 1:
        odds = random.randint(1,100)
        if odds <= 81:
            hit = 1
            totalhits = totalhits + 1
        else:
            hit = 0
    return totalhits

for i in range(1,1000000):
    totalhits  = baseball()
    if totalhits >= 56:
        break
    attempts = attempts + 1

print("Attempt " + str(attempts) + " succeeded.")
```

Solution 2 : Using `global`

```py
import random
attempts = 0
totalhits = 0
def baseball():
    global totalhits
    totalhits = 0
    hit = 1
    while hit == 1:
        odds = random.randint(1,100)
        if odds <= 81:
            hit = 1
            totalhits = totalhits + 1
        else:
            hit = 0

for i in range(1,1000000):
    baseball()
    if totalhits >= 56:
        break
    attempts = attempts + 1

print("Attempt " + str(attempts) + " succeeded.")
```

Comment: If you want to down vote an answer leave a comment what is wrong with it. Dont take out your frustration on other's answer. Down voting a answer without leaving comment is not helping anyone in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning 'totalhits' from your function.
So, everytime you compare the value of 'totalhits', you are comparing it with the initial value of 0.

You can change the for loop as

```
for i in range(1,1000000):
     totalhits = baseball()
     if totalhits >= 56:
         break attempts = attempts + 1
```

to get the desired result.